# Change index based on str.contains() pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi Guys i want to change index of my dataframe based on result of str.contains.

a quick example

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'Product':['Banana_1','Banana_2','Orange_a','Orange_b'],
    'Value':[5.10,5.00,2.10,2.00]})

df2 = df[df['Product'].str.contains('Banana')]

print(df2)
```

is there a way to use df2 filter to change df1 index?

Thanks

Comment: What does *change* mean?

Comment: In this data frame index was set as regular, 0,1,2,3, i want to define a specific index every time banana is true on str.contains()

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the index based on cell values like the following, which is (I think) along the lines of what you want:

```
In [28]: df.index = [i  if 'Banana' in df.iloc[i,0] else i+len(df) for i in range(len(df))]

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
    Product  Value
0  Banana_1    5.1
1  Banana_2    5.0
6  Orange_a    2.1
7  Orange_b    2.0
```

Comment: Thanks is that what i want, sorry for bad MRE, i'm new to this thing.

Comment: @drikorf81 You can, and should, just edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
In [1230]: index_list = df2.index.tolist()
In [1236]: index_map = {}                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [1237]: for i in index_list: 
      ...:     index_map[i] = 'myindex' 
      ...:                              

In [1250]: df.rename(index=index_map, inplace=True)                                                                                                                                                         

In [1251]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1251]: 
          Product  Value
myindex  Banana_1    5.1
myindex  Banana_2    5.0
2        Orange_a    2.1
3        Orange_b    2.0
```